# Issue with migrating android app to Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, migration, crashlytics

I am migrating an existing android app to firebase crashlytics. As of yesterday I was having an issue of not getting the crashes reported on the firebase console, while the implementation was working. I think there was an issue with the sdk firebase dependency. I tried to change the library dependencies versions on the build.gradle files in order to get around the issue but now I am getting this error on the console:

```
    In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[17.1.
2]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-       iid@[17.1.2], but fire
base-iid version was 20.1.5.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the artifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@{strictly 17.0.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-fcm@{strictly 5.5.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl@{strictly 16.3.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@17.6.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@16.3.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@{strictly 17.6.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-fcm@5.+
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@{strictly 20.1.5}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@17.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@{strictly 16.3.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@{strictly 16.3.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@20.1.5

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
uild.gradle file.
```

Any ideas on how I should proceed? Do I need to change the version of the sdk crashlytics dependency :
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0'

Comment: Post your build.gradle file. In general, you should always use the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your versions should make the error go away. If you're not seeing crashes coming into your dashboard afterwards, either write into [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) or post a screenshot of your [debug](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android#enable_debug_logging) crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Use below configuration if your facing build issues using Android studio 4.1

- Android Gradle Plugin Version 3.6.0
- Gradle Version 6.5

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
```